# Set correctly the path for a File Constructor to work in a Jar File

Tags: java, jar, path

I'm writing code to play a .wav file.
All works in my IDE (eclipse) but when I try to export in a jar file, the sound doesn't play! It seems to me a path problem.

Here the code to play (only relevant parts).

```
File audioFile = new File(audioFilePath);
AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
```

Here some solutions that I've tried (one for line)

```
audioFilePath=(SoundGame.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").toURI()).toString()+mySourceRelativePath;
audioFilePath=SoundGame.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()+mySourceRelativePath;
audioFilePath=System.getProperty("user.dir")+mySourceRelativePath;
audioFilePath=this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(mySourcePath);
```

When I try to use this same code (one of these lines) to upload images all works, even in my jar file but not with the sound. 
Please, I can't understand how to change the path.
Hope in help.

Comment: There is no way to do what you're asking. A resource in a JAR file is *not* a file, so you can't use it as a file.

Comment: Note that it *is* possible to play a WAV file that's inside a JAR - just not the way you're asking about.

Comment: May you post me a working code for .wav in a JAR, please?

Comment: Use Class#getResource("/path/to/resource") which returns a URL then use [AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(URL)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream(java.net.URL))

Answer (score 0):

If a file is in a JAR, *it's not an actual file*, so it *doesn't have a path*.

You can use an `InputStream` instead. A `File` can only point to a file on disk, but an `InputStream` can be anything you can read from. You could even stream audio over a network connection this way.

```
AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(mySourcePath));
```

Alternatively, you can use a URL. `getResource` returns a URL, while `getResourceAsStream` returns an `InputStream`. Not everything that has an `InputStream` has a URL, but resources always have URLs.

```
URL resourceURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(mySourcePath);
AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(resourceURL);
```